SIM card not being detected on my NRF9160 custom board
I´ve designed a board that uses the NRF9160 SOC as its main controller and modem for LTE, right now everything works besides the SIM card. When I try to read the status from it the response I get indicates "Universal Subscriber Identity Module (USIM) card failure".
Here is what I tried for troubleshooting:

First I thought it could be bad soldering so  reflowed the SoC and the SIM tray in two different boards, had no changes.
Scoped the SIM tray pins to check if there was any activity when the modem was activated, all pins passed the test.
Tried different SIM cards, they all had the same problem.
Tried one of the SIM cards in another modem, it was detected and worked, scoped the pins and it´s working at around 1.95 V, the Nrf9160 works at 1.80 V, so it confirms it´s a class C sim card.

Here are my board drawings:
Bottom with SIM card tray.

Top with TVS.

Here are my schematics:
Socket with TVS:

Connection to Nrf9160

I also tried to remove the TVS and connect the pins from the SoC directly into the SIM tray, same problem.
The TVS I´m using is the TPD3F303DQDR
What else could I try to troubleshoot this problem?

@jsotola just added it

Assuming that it is indeed a SIM card connection issue (because we don't know other details about how you've designed the modem itself), have you captured the behavior of the clock and data lines?

@Colin Yes, i have, the clock signal is present and the I/O line goes high as it should, every pin outputs a signal.

Solved the problem, it was never the sim card or the connections. When scoping the VCC pin on the socket i realized that there was a really fast drop to arround 1V, that´s not enought to power the sim, so i put a 100nf capacitor between VCC and GND and now communication works. This capacitor wasn´t present on Nordic´s hardware design guidelines so it´s interesting to add one if a board is beign designed.
